# Stumped on the nuances of rendering a React string in a component

Tags: node.js

Start with the usual npx react-create-app, and replace App.js with this stripped down version:

```
const MySvg = () => {
    return (
        <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" strokeWidth="3" fill="red"/>
        </svg>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <header className="App-header">
                <MySvg/>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This correctly displays a simple circle. But if I try to pass in the same string as a variable instead of 'hard coded':

```
const MySvg = () => {
    const svgData = '<svg height="100" width="100">' +
        '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" strokeWidth="3" fill="red"/>' +
        '</svg>'
    return (
        {svgData}
    );
}

// this is unchanged...
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <header className="App-header">
                <MySvg/>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

It blows up miserably with:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {svgData}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Admittedly I'm still a novice at nodejs, and I'm grateful in advance for your assist!

Comment: In ES6, there are shorthand property names for object initializer ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)). So, `{svgData}` is the same as`{"svgData": svgData}"`. Also, svgData is of type string, and not a React Element. If you changed it to `return svgData`, it still will not give you a circle.